# How to delete word and all words after that

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have this URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=611377065590688&set=a.320150204713377.74079.229899403738458&type=1
```

I want to be:

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=611377065590688
```

I want to delete `&` and all words after it. How I can do it?

Comment: With the `Backspace` button, probably.

Answer (score 3):

Put your cursor before `&set` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. Then delete.

Answer (score 3):

In notepad++ go to

```
 Search / Replace
```

Enable `Regular Expression` in the Search Mode at the bottom of the dialog

In the `Find what` field put

```
&set.*
```

Leave the replace field empty, and click `Replace All`

This will search for `&set` followed by any number of characters and replace with nothing.